# How to write groovy test for main class of Spring-boot application thast uses CommandLineRunner

Tags: spring-boot, testing, groovy, spock

My class is like:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
class Test implements CommandLineRunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    //some code
  }
}
```

How do I pass argument to run method? Currently written test as:

```groovy
def "loads for class"() {
  expect:
  true
}
```

but it can't find the args for run method and fails.

Comment: What is the question? Your test does absolutely nothing. Why are you expecting it to call anything?

Comment: Actually this Test class's run method is main method that further calls the service class so I have to call the service class from it and hence test this call.

Answer (score 0):

If you use classic spring integration test, you can use:

```
@SpringBootTest(args = {"YOUR", "ARGS", "GO", "HERE"})
```